# How to Change the message font in MS Bot Framework?

Tags: css, sass, botframework

This is my directory structure.

```
-root
  -Public
     -index.html
     -css
       -botchat.css
     -js
       -botchat.js
  -src
    -scss
      -botchat.scss
      -botchat-fullwindow.scss
      -includes
```

I want to change the font of the message which is sent and received. 
This is the changes that I have made in the botchat.scss file

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'mark';
    font-weight: 'normal';
    src: url('mrkflthn-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('mrkflthn-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}

body .wc-app, .wc-app button, .wc-app input, .wc-app textarea {

    font-family: mark;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing : 1.5px;
}

.wc-app button {........
```

I added 2 files **mrkflthn-webfont.woff2** and **mrkflthn-webfont.woff** to the root folder. When I run the index.html I cannot see the font changed. Where I am going wrong?
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

When using the webchat, you only need your `Public` part of your directory. The other files are used to generate the `Public` files: it looks like you only changed the source but haven't rebuilt your Webchat so your changes will not be present on your `botchat.js` and `botchat.css` files.

To have those changes on your files:

- Follow the process to rebuild the files described in Webchat's github project here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#building-web-chat
- Redeploy your files

Or if it's only a small CSS change, you can do it directly in your `botchat.css` file (beware of overwriting it next time you build the webchat...)

Comment: I am using npm run prepublish to build the files and then moving the files to Public folder. I have the changed the color in botchat.scss file all of these chages are reflecting correctly but only the font is not reflecting properly.

Comment: That would be great to put those info in your question :-) 

Any error in the console like problem when loading the fonts?

Comment: one more thing: you added your fonts to the root folder, but your css file is in the css folder and you are using `url()` without jumping to the root folder.

Comment: So should i put the font files in the src folder or in the css folder?

Comment: You have the choice: if in the css folder, let the url like that. If in the root, add "../"